# UNIQUE constraint error. Custom User Model

Tags: django

Делаю кастомизированную модель пользователя (model & forms ниже) - вместо username хочу использовать email. Вылезает непонятная ошибка:

```
IntegrityError at /reg/
UNIQUE constraint failed: users_customuser.username
```

Ругается на строчку form.save() в views.py
Как я понимаю, ошибка означает, что мы пытаемся создать существующего пользователя. Но это не так. Больше одного пользователя создать не удается

**Пробовал:** удалить все миграции и БД и заново `makemigrations` & `migrate`.
Одного пользователя создать дает, больше - нет

models

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, email, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):

    if not email:
        raise ValueError('User must have an email')

    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email)
    )
    user.active = is_active
    user.staff = is_staff
    user.admin = is_admin
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_staff(self, email, password=None):
    user = self.create_user(
        email=email,
        password=password,
        is_staff=True,
    )

def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):

    user = self.create_user(
        email=email,
        password=password,
        is_staff=True,
        is_admin=True,
    )

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        unique=True,
        max_length=255,
    )

    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin
```

_forms:

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password = forms.CharField(max_length=255, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=255, widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['email',]

    def clean_password2(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        if password and password2 and password != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Password must be the same')
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password2"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

views:

```
def signup_view(request):

    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема кроется в классе, от которого вы наследуетесь

```
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    An abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with
    admin-compliant permissions.

    Username and password are required. Other fields are optional.
    """
    username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator() if six.PY3 else ASCIIUsernameValidator()

    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
```

Как можете видеть, у `AbstractUser` уже имеется поле `username`, которое должно быть уникальным. В вашем случае, все поля из AbstractUser были перенесены в CustomUser.

Если вы ходите исправить эту логику с уникальным `username`, то либо переопределите поле `username`, чтобы оно не было уникальным, либо наследуйтесь от `AbstractBaseUser`

Как еще один вариант - добавьте в форму регистрации поле `username`, которое тоже нужно будет заполнить, но вход проверяйте по email.